# deny root users on remote machines to change ldap users details

Tags: linux, freebsd, openldap

I want to prevent root users on remote machines to change the ldap users accounts details and keep it only permitted to the local server root.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state which LDAP server, but if, as seems probable, you're using OpenLDAP, you can't stop root users from doing *anything.* You shouldn't *have* root users. The root user is for use by the server itself. Nobody else should use it. Nobody else should even know about it. You should have admin users, defined in the directory itself, and then you can specify their acces rights very extensively in the slapd configuration.